# How can we handle Update and Delete in Azure data management gateway

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Currently, we are mirroring our local SQL server Database with Azure SQL Server Database. For this, we are using Azure Data Management gateway but the problem is we are not able to handle the update or delete scenario. Update and Delete are not reflecting in Azure SQL Server database(Mirror).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What type of activity are you using in your pipeline? I'm assuming a simple copy activity?

My suggestion would be to have a copy activity that lands a clone of the on premises data in the Azure SQL DB first, maybe in a staging schema set of table or something. Then have a second downstream activity that performs a stored procedure execution activity. You can code a MERGE statement or whatever in the procedure to output the data into a separate table.

It sounds like you almost want a secondary node for your SQL Server in Azure. Maybe just use an availability group?! SQL 2014 or higher required on prem though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [Transactional Replication to Azure SQL database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/), with transactional replication, Azure SQL database acts as a subscriber, update/delete changes you made in on-premises SQL Server database will be reflected in Azure SQL database.